# How to set selected option of select element by its ID?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<select id="comboBox">
    <option id="1">One</option>
    <option id="2">Two</option>
    <option id="3">Three</option>
    <option id="4">Four</option>
</select>
```

I want to select option with ID 3. Is there any way how to do it without loop? I expect something like this

```
$("#comboBox").val("3");
```

but with ID instead of value. (So I mean to access that option as member of comboBox, not through selector like `document.getElementById('3');`)

Comment: `document.getElementById('3');`?

Comment: I meant to set it somehow through the 'comboBox' element.

Comment: Please rephrase your question so that it explains what exactly you want to happen.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("3").selected=true;
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("comboBox").options[2].selected=true;
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("comboBox").selectedIndex=2;
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("comboBox").options.namedItem("3").selected=true;
</script>
```

For the last one see [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement#namedItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement#namedItem%28%29) and 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_select_options.asp

You could skip the reference to options for the shorter `document.getElementById("comboBox").namedItem("3").selected=true;`

Answer (score 5):

Use `document.querySelector` to retrieve an option, then use either `setAttribute` to set the selected state or set the selected state directly.

```js
const getOptionById = id => 
  document.querySelector(`#comboBox > option[id="${id}"]`);

// direct set
getOptionById(3).selected = true;

// setAttribute
setTimeout(() => getOptionById(4).setAttribute(`selected`, true), 3000);
```

```html
<select id="comboBox">
    <option id="1">One</option>
    <option id="2">Two</option>
    <option id="3">Three</option>
    <option id="4">Four</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$("#2").attr({"selected": true});
```

Note I'm using JQuery selector and `.attr` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,if your id is in the same order

```
document.getElementById("comboBox").selectedIndex = 2;
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gZ3sS/)

Answer (score 0):

[selectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534624%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a property of HTMLSelectElement, you can get its index using the `index` property, so you can do the following:

```
document.getElementById("comboBox").selectedIndex = document.getElementById('3').index;
```

**Updated:** <kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/gZ3sS/6/)</kbd>

**Updating option on Button Click event:** <kbd>[New Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/E2Pxk/)</kbd>

**Updating option on Button Click event in decreasing order:** <kbd>[Another Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/TTqEv/)</kbd>

Comment: This doesn't work, really. What is `document.getElementById('3').index`?

Comment: It should work and **Demo** is also working. `document.getElementById('3').index` for getting index of `option` having 3 `id`. I have updated my answer also

Comment: I stand corrected. Suppose in an earlier version the fiddle scripting was in the html-header. `document.getElementById('3').index` is an existing property, supposedly because it's an `option`, interesting.

Comment: Not understand you again. Can you explain me @KooiInc

Comment: This is almost what I wanted, but I expect instead of `document.getElementById('3')` access it from the "comboBox" element.

Comment: What you want now @juice?