# document.getElementById("").selected = true don't work probably

Tags: javascript, php, html

**When I clicked on "btnCalendar", the option "current" will be selected. But it doesn't work. It just show "current" option and then change back into "default" option again.**

This is my javaScript code and I wrote them in head tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function currentAcademicYear(){
        document.getElementById("current").selected = true;
    }
</script>
```

This is my HTML code

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Academic Year</td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option selected hidden id="default">Select Academic Year</option>
                    <optgroup label="Select Academic Year">
                        <?php
                            for ($i=5; $i > 0; $i--) 
                            {
                                $year = $currentYear-$i;
                                $yearB4year = $year-1;
                                echo "<option>".$yearB4year." - ".$year."</option>";
                            }
                        ?>
                        <option id="current">
                            <?php
                                $yearAfterCurrentYear = $currentYear + 1;
                                echo $currentYear." - ".$yearAfterCurrentYear;
                            ?>
                        </option>
                        <option >
                            <?php
                                $year2AfterCurrentYear = $yearAfterCurrentYear + 1;
                                echo $yearAfterCurrentYear." - ".$year2AfterCurrentYear;
                            ?>
                        </option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><button class="far fa-calendar" id="btnCalendar" onclick = "currentAcademicYear()"></button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Your `<button>` should also have `type="button"`. Currently, it's a "submit" button so it's submitting your `<form>` and reloading the page.

Comment: @Dai I don't see any other element with that id in the posted code.

Comment: You'll want `document.getElementById("current").selected = true;`. You don't put quotes around boolean literals.

Comment: Thank you..It works now :D  I missed type="button". Thank you so much seniors :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set selected option of select element by its ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23218368/how-to-set-selected-option-of-select-element-by-its-id)

Comment: @UmairKhan not help much but it help me somehow xD

Answer (score 0):

I hope the code below will help you out

```
<form>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Academic Year</td>
        <td>
            <select id="Change_Value">
                <option selected hidden id="default">Select Academic Year</option>
                <optgroup label="Select Academic Year">
                    <?php
                        for ($i=5; $i > 0; $i--) 
                        {
                            $year = $currentYear-$i;
                            $yearB4year = $year-1;
                            echo "<option>".$yearB4year." - ".$year."</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                    <option id="current">
                        <?php
                            $yearAfterCurrentYear = $currentYear + 1;
                            echo $currentYear." - ".$yearAfterCurrentYear;
                        ?>
                    </option>
                    <option >
                        <?php
                            $year2AfterCurrentYear = $yearAfterCurrentYear + 1;
                            echo $yearAfterCurrentYear." - ".$year2AfterCurrentYear;
                        ?>
                    </option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><button class="far fa-calendar btnCalendar" id="btnCalendar"></button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Code of JQuery

```
$('.btnCalendar').click(function(){ 
$('#Change_Value').val($(this).data('val')).trigger('change');
```

})